# how to make an array data from database before transfer using curl php

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I want to ask about `array` in php.

I have build `curl php` and it is successfully transferring the data. But my problem is that I want to transfer that by using array.

This is my code:

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT domain_name  FROM domain";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
  {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {

      $domain= $row['domain_name'];
      $content= $row['domain_content']; // get values row-wise from db
      $reason = $row['reason'];

      $curlHandle = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, '192.168.100.2/update.php');
      curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
      curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'domain_name='.$domain.);
      curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
      curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

      if (!curl_exec($curlHandle)) 
      {
        //echo 'everything was successful';
      }
      else 
      {
        echo 'An error has occurred: ' . curl_error($curlHandle);
      } 

    } /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

  } /* END OF NUM ROWS RESULT IS MORE THAN 0 */
  else 
  {
    echo "0 results";
  }
?>
```

From code above, the system will running in a loop when sending the data until all data from database was transferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array like

```
$curl_array = [
  'domain' => $row['domain_name'],
  'content' => $row['domain_content'],
  'reason' => $row['reason']
];
```

if your PHP is older than 5.4 like this

```
$curl_array = array(
  'domain' => $row['domain_name'],
  'content' => $row['domain_content'],
  'reason' => $row['reason']
);
```

You can read about arrays at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Also i would suggest JSON encoding (`json_encode()`) the data before you send it by updating `curl_setopt`

```
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'data='.json_encode($curl_array).);
```

Note that you would have to update the script `192.168.100.2/update.php` to account for array and also to `json_decode()`

Eg:

```
$curl_post = json_decode($_POST['data']);
$domain => $curl_post['domain_name'];
$content => $curl_post['domain_content'];
$reason => $curl_post['reason'];
```

Full code:

```
  <?php
    $sql = "SELECT domain_name  FROM domain";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 

    {

    // get the values from db ans populate array
    $curl_array = [
      'domain' => $row['domain_name'],
      'content' => $row['domain_content'],
      'reason' => $row['reason']
    ];

    $curlHandle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, '192.168.100.2/update.php');
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'data='.json_encode($curl_array).);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);



    if (!curl_exec($curlHandle)) 
    {
    //echo 'everything was successful';
    }
    else 
    {
    echo 'An error has occurred: ' . curl_error($curlHandle);
    } 
    }
    } 
     else 
    {
    echo "0 results";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: so when data transfer to 192.168.100.2, i must use "data" right?? @aharen

Comment: @MuhammadYusufAhmadShahRudd yes or you could change 'data' to in `curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'data='.json_encode($curl_array).);` to any value that you like

Comment: Try `var_dump(json_decode($_POST['data']));` you should get the array posted with that :)

Comment: before this i use  ' $domain_name = $_POST['domain_name']; ' and i will save all data into text file like this '$txt = $domain_name;'....  @aharen

Comment: @MuhammadYusufAhmadShahRudd Please take a look, i have updated the answer :)

Comment: @MuhammadYusufAhmadShahRudd Test and let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: can i ask u basic question @aharen?? after data have been send.. i want to store in text file.. so i write like this var_dump(json_decode($_POST['data']));

then for writing to text file... i write like this $txt='data';

Comment: `var_dump()` is used for testing, to dump the data and see what's been returned. Do `$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);` and then `$txt = $data;` and i assume the `$txt` is being written to file right?

Comment: when i try to send the data.. the web page blank...  @aharen

Comment: @MuhammadYusufAhmadShahRudd which page is blank? & is the data written to the text file?

Comment: when i send the data.. i make a echo 'data have been transferred' for the output.. but all the output that i set now displayed... by the way @aharen how can i personal contact u... such as facebook...??

Comment: @MuhammadYusufAhmadShahRudd i see, is curl working? sure im on twitter @ aharen :)

Comment: i was follow u on twitter @aharen